# Filter by comparing a nested property to a search term

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

In my typescript I want to filter by comparing a nested property to a search term.
For example I have an array of object like so:

```
var array = [
      {
        game: 'Cricket',
        team: ['Sally','Bob','John'],
      },
      {
        game: 'Basketball',
        team: ['Linda', 'George'],
      }
]
```

If I search For 'John' then the result should be:

```
[
  {
    game: 'Cricket',
    team: ['John']
   }
]
```

How ca I achieve that?

Comment: Which other search criterias you want to support? Can you write down signature of a function you want to implement? serchByGame, searchByItem? Does this array always have same structure?

Comment: search by item only and the array always have the same strucuture

Comment: The `team` of the filtered one should be `['Sally','Bob','John']` or just `['John']`?

Comment: Initially the teams have array length around 10+ from that I just want to show the ['John'] (i.e. the string which i have entered in text box- e.g. John)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as i understand. you want to search the element which has for ex "john" as a team member?
here is a quick solution that you can alter to your needs

```js
const a = [{
    game: 'Cricket',
    team: ['Sally', 'Bob', 'John']
  },
  {
    game: 'Basketball',
    team: ['Linda', 'George']
  }
]
const target = "John";
// this filters the array by checking if the current element fits the criteria and returns the element
const res = [];
a.map(el =>  el.team.includes(target) 
  ? res.push({...el, team: [target]}) 
  : false
);

console.log(res);
```

Edit: here is a fix. you need to use map instead if you want to do it one line, otherwise you need to loop through the resulted array and mutate it.

Comment: Thanks But,
The result should return only john- not all the three sally,bob,John

Comment: You can edit the structure of the resulted array, i only showed how to filter

Comment: ok. I already used the filter but not getting the expected result- it returning whole array - that's my question

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expectations, following should work:

### Using reduce

```js
type Game = {
  game: string
  team: string[]
}

const games = [
  {
    game: 'Cricket',
    team: ['Sally', 'Bob', 'John']
  },
  {
    game: 'Basketball',
    team: ['Linda', 'George']
  }
]

const filterByTeamMember = (games: Game[], member: string): Game[] =>
  games.reduce<Game[]>(
    (p, c) => (c.team.includes(member) ? [...p, { ...c, team: [member] }] : p),
    []
  )

console.log(filterByTeamMember(games, 'Linda'))
// OUTPUT
// [ { game: 'Basketball', team: [ 'Linda' ] } ]
```

### Using flatMap

```js
const filterByTeamMember = (games: Game[], member: string): Game[] =>
  games.flatMap((game) => (game.team.includes(member) ? [{ ...game, team: [member] }] : []))
```